# Why does Korra address Katara and Tenzin by (first) name only?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

This is something that's always bugged me, but I shrugged it off as a person who watched ATLA before TLOK. So I think of Katara as really 'Katara' instead of 'Master Katara', as opposed to say... viewing Pakku as really 'Master Pakku', since in ATLA we first meet the guy as an old guy who teaches Aang.

**Question:**

Why doesn't Korra address Tenzin / Katara as like 'Master Tenzin' / 'Master Katara' ?

I forgot how in TLOK other people Korra's age address Tenzin or how the ATLA peeps addressed their elders, but eh if they don't have titles or something, then what's up with them too?

Comment: If you call him Master Tenzin, you now need to explain to the audience why you don't call her Master Katara

Comment: @Valorum then why don't you call katara as master katara?

Comment: Because the audience [know her as Katara](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266878/why-does-korra-refer-to-katara-and-tenzin-by-1st-name-only?noredirect=1#comment735377_266878) and it would be weird to call her something else. Remember that the purpose of TV shows is not internal consistency, it's eyeballs on seats

Comment: @user14111 How about 'Why does Korra refer to Katara and Tenzin by 1st name only instead of, say, Tenzin / Katara as like 'Master Tenzin' / 'Master Katara' ?' Is that better?

Comment: @Valorum What audience? Not everyone has seen ATLA before TLOK.

Comment: @BCLC - I'd be willing to bet that a very significant portion of Legend of Korra's first-run viewership were already Avatar fans, or they wouldn't have made it

Comment: @Valorum and so what if they have? i think they'd feel like 'wow. the katara is now "master katara". that's so cool! i'm getting old though!

Comment: @BCLC - Changes like that would need to be addressed constantly to remind people why it's different. Not changing it means that you don't have to address it at all.

Comment: @Valorum 'addressed constantly' --> Why? It's quite obvious Katara is MUCH older. Katara even has a different voice actor!

Comment: Because she isn't being Korra's master in every scene. If you call her master Katara, you need to then add in a line about her being Katara's teacher to explain it.

Comment: @Valorum 1 line? or several lines to address constantly? Which is it?

Comment: a line in every episode, at least until people have gotten used to the idea. I remember when they recast a character in my favourite soap and they needed to keep having people refer to her *by name* several times per scene for a few weeks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Katara:

From the comics, we know that Korra has known Katara since early childhood. They seem to have a familial relationship, meaning no stuffy titles are needed.

[image: An older Katara teaching a young Korra. Katara is waterbending and saying "Now watch me, Korra. Waterbending is all about slow, calm movements."]

## Tenzin:

In the actual series, Korra initially does address Tenzin as "Master Tenzin."

> KORRA: Master Tenzin, I'm so glad you're here. I can't wait to get started.
> <sub>*The Legend of Korra*, Book 1: "Air", episode 1: "Welcome to Republic City"</sub>

She gives this up later in the episode, though. I would chalk that up to various established personality and context differences between Aang and Korra. Aang was raised as a monk in a very traditional, respect-oriented environment, seen as somewhat archaic even by the time of the original show. For example, see how he calls Zuko "Sifu" against Zuko's wishes. Korra is generally more headstrong and was raised in a less rigid, more modern environment. She also soon had a closer relationship with Tenzin than Aang did with Pakku. She lived with Tenzin and his family for an extended period of time, while Aang was forced to move on from Pakku quickly.

The original show actually sets the precedence that familiarity can trump formality. Aang initially calls Toph and Zuko "Sifu" because he was (re)introduced to them as teachers. He doesn't do this with Katara, who he befriended prior to her teaching him.

> KATARA: Hey, you never called me Sifu Katara.
> <sub>*Avatar: The Last AIrbender*, Book 2: "Earth", episode 9: "Bitter Work"</sub>

Comment: Plus, something we could add is that as Korra is the Avatar, she is the reincarnation of Katara's husband and Tenzin's father. I'm not sure if these too would have wanted her to call them *master*.